# Unwrap Anchor Tag based on href content or class name

Tags: jquery, slicknav

I have the following code which checks all anchor tags and removes only the anchor tags if their respective href holds only "#" and this works.

```js
$("a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href == '#') {
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
    }
});
```

However this code is not working on the below html for some reason.

```html
<a class="slicknav_item slicknav_row" tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" 
   role="menuitem" href="#" style="outline: medium none;">About</a>
```

To get a better picture the code that works is on an normal unordered list while the issue is happening when the menu changes if on mobile devices. I am using slicknav as a responsive menu.

Comment: is this in a dom ready state? is that item dynamically created?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be related to what you posted, you might need to provide more code for a solution.

Comment: @DanielA.White A The script is being called after the menu and I included it there.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan why its not related? The code checks for all anchor tags within the page so the html posted should be affected.

Comment: @Jason I'm saying the problem isn't in the code you posted. In an isolated environment it works fine: http://codepen.io/jessekernaghan/pen/ogWOpp which usually points to the problem being either in a different part of your code, or the problem is how this code is being implemented.

Comment: could cut that to a simple one liner `$("a[href=#]").contents().unwrap()`  http://jsfiddle.net/xv5tq5L9/

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Ah ok understood :) Yes I debugged all the code but perhaps I am missing something... I will try clean again to test this.